# Securely deleting Volume Shadow Service (VSS) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, deletion, data-recovery

Suppose that VSS is enabled and snapshots exist. If I run a program to wipe the free disk space on my drive, would this delete the VSS snapshots? It might do since the program works by filling up the drive by creating a growing file, and once the file gets really large, Windows might delete the VSS copies due to lack of space. Is this right?

Comment: First of all, what does your question have to do with `[data-leakage]`? Please avoid using unrelated tags. Secondly, your first question is easily answered by using Google. Have you attempted to google this before asking? Also first you ask about "using a program to wipe empty space", then you ask if Windows will delete a file by itself. Which one is it?

Comment: @MechMK1 Where did you find a reputable answer to question 1 (which has now been edited out by schroeder for some reason)? Regarding your "Also first you ask about...", you clearly do not understand the question/topic at hand.